# OpenCV Error: Null pointer with canny

Tags: c, opencv

I'm trying to learn C and OpenCV. I'm using the following code, inspired from *O'Reilly Learning OpenCV*, but I get an error and the image doesn't show as expected. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
# include "cv.h"
# include "highgui.h"

IplImage * doCanny(IplImage *in, double lowThresh, double highThresh, int aperture) {

    if(1 != in->nChannels){
        return 0;
    }

    IplImage *out = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(in), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCanny(in, out, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture);
    return out;
}

/* This layout works with other functions like cvPyrdown, but for some reason it doesn't work with cvCanny */   
int main() {

    double lowThresh = 50;
    double highThresh = 150;
    int aperture = 3;

    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("/tmp/lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    IplImage *out = doCanny(img, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture);

    cvNamedWindow("Example2-6", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    cvShowImage("Example2-6", out);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseImage(&out);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2-6");

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get on Mac OS X Yosemite is:

> OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in cvGetMat, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/.../opencv-2.4.11/.../array.cpp, line 2382

Comment: please, use opencv's c++ api, not the outdated, and no more maintained c-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *jpg* image is most likely a three-channel image. You pass this image as `in` into your `doCanny()` function. The following code will cause the `doCanny()` function to return 0:

```
if(1 != in->nChannels){
    return 0;
}
```

Then you don't check if the return value of your `doCanny()` function is valid. Therefore you pass a null pointer to the following function which might cause your null pointer error:

```
cvShowImage("Example2-6", out);
```

In order to make your code working with three-channel images, you should convert the `in` image in your `doCanny()` function into a single-channel image:

```
IplImage * doCanny(IplImage *in, double lowThresh, double highThresh, int aperture) {
    IplImage *out = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(in), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    /* Convert the three-channel input image into a single-channel image. */
    IplImage* oneChannel = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(in), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
    cvCvtColor(in, oneChannel, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cvCanny(oneChannel, out, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture);
    return out;
}
```

Alternatively, you can directly load the input image as single-channel image by passing `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` as second parameter to `cvLoadImage()`:

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("/tmp/lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Anyway, you should always check if the values returned by functions are valid.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me :

```
 #include "opencv/cv.h"
 #include "opencv/highgui.h"
 #include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"

 using namespace cv;
 IplImage * doCanny(IplImage *in, double lowThresh, double highThresh, int aperture) 
  {
    if(1 != in->nChannels)
    { return 0; }

    IplImage *out = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(in),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 0);
    cvCanny(in, out, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture);
    return (out);
  }


 int main() 
 {
    double lowThresh = 50;
    double highThresh = 150;
    int aperture = 3;

    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("/tmp/lena.jpg",0);
    IplImage *out = doCanny(img, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture);

    cvNamedWindow("Example2-6", 0);
    cvShowImage("Example2-6", out);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseImage(&out);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2-6");
    return 0;
 }
```

If problem continue then visit

[Opencv error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420068/opencv-error-null-pointer-null-array-pointer-is-passed-in-cvgetmat)

[Opencv error2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604793/opencv-null-pointer-null-array-pointer-is-passed-in-cvgetmat)